# using awk to print two columns one after another

Tags: awk

I'm trying to simply print column `$4` followed by `$NF` with the following data:

```
       000   0     00    NUL '\0' (null character)   100   64    40    @
       001   1     01    SOH (start of heading)      101   65    41    A
       002   2     02    STX (start of text)         102   66    42    B
       003   3     03    ETX (end of text)           103   67    43    C
       004   4     04    EOT (end of transmission)   104   68    44    D
       005   5     05    ENQ (enquiry)               105   69    45    E
       006   6     06    ACK (acknowledge)           106   70    46    F
       007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)             107   71    47    G
       010   8     08    BS  '\b' (backspace)        110   72    48    H
```

so that I get:

```
NUL
SOH
STX
ETX
EOT
ENQ
ACK
BEL
BS
@
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

Where `awk` waits for the first operation to finish then performs a printout of the next column.

I tried:

```
awk '{print $4} {print $NF}'
```

but this obviously just prints them one after the other and mixes them all up.

I'm trying to better understand `awk` and messing around, bear with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK you would need to store the `$NF` values and print them in an `END` block

```
awk '{a[NR] = $NF; print $4} END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) print a[i]}' file
```

or make two passes over the file

```
awk 'NR==FNR {print $4; next} {print $NF}' file file
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

@steeldriver already showed how to do this entirely in awk and while this is more than you need for this specific problem, consider also the extremely useful [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Decorate-sort-undecorate_idiom) for problems like this:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print 1, NR, $4 ORS 2, NR, $NF}' file | sort -nk1,2 | cut -f3-
NUL
SOH
STX
ETX
EOT
ENQ
ACK
BEL
BS
@
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

You could implement something similar entirely in GNU awk (for arrays of arrays and `sorted_in`) as:

```
$ awk '
    { a[1][NR]=$4; a[2][NR]=$NF }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (i in a) for (j in a[i]) print a[i][j]
    }
' file
NUL
SOH
STX
ETX
EOT
ENQ
ACK
BEL
BS
@
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $4; a = ((a) ? a ORS : "") $NF} END{print a}' file
```

A simpler and more efficient way as suggested by @EdMorton is

```
$ awk '{print $4; a=a $NF ORS} END{printf "%s", a}' file
```

---

Using `awk` and `datamash`:

```bash
$ awk '{print $4, $NF}' file | datamash -W --output-delimiter $'\n' transpose
```

The following command gives the output as:

```
$ awk '{print $4, $NF}' ex | datamash -W  transpose 
NUL     SOH     STX     ETX     EOT ENQ      ACK     BEL     BS
@       A       B       C       D     E        F     G       H
```

In this output values are separated by `tab` that can be changed by setting [`--output-delimiter`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Invoking-datamash.html#index-_002d_002doutput_002ddelimiter) to `\n`.

```
$ awk '{print $4, $NF}' ex | datamash -W --output-delimiter $'\n' transpose
NUL
SOH
STX
ETX
EOT
ENQ
ACK
BEL
BS
@
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```